# how to retain view after addSubview of UIViewController with ARC

Tags: memory-management, uiview

How to handle situation when I use ARC and add view of UIViewController?

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[someView addSubview:vc.view]; //this retain vc.view
```

because addSubview retain onlu view, not controller, so controller is released. Before ARC there was a way to retain controller as long as neede, but how to prevent ARC to release View Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar situation solved by declaring vc as property with default strong attribute.

Comment: I think this is only solution at the moment. View Controller will remain in memory as long as declared property will not change, and allways one copy of controller will be retined, even if it's removed from parent view controller (using removeFromParentViewController since iOS 5.0)

Answer (score 0):

`#define AntiARCRetain(...) void *retainedThing = (bridge_retained void *)__VA_ARGS; retainedThing = retainedThing`

And then call   AntiARCRetain(controller);

Comment: It retains the object.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you need a new ViewController there?
You should just add your View as Subview and handle everything with the ViewController of "someView"

Comment: because view is not released when viewcontroller is released, and this cause crash if you'll try to do anything with view that is related to (already) released controller.