# copy vs strong properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa

I am fresher in iOS and I want to know that when we should use `copy` in a property, e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
```

vs

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* name;`
```

What is the difference between `retain` and `copy`, and when should I use one but not the other?

Comment: Generally, I use retain for objects like NSString, array and other variables. but when I am taking outlets of UIView, or any Instance as a UIViewController I am taking strong. Else actually I do not know the difference.

Comment: @ArpitParekh strong === retain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796476/property-definitions-with-arc-strong-or-retain

Comment: But, when I am taking UIViewController as a variable, and I need to assign it as a strong proper, If I make it as a retain then my app crashes...this link support this. When adding it as a subview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144959/how-to-retain-view-after-addsubview-of-uiviewcontroller-with-arc

Comment: @ArpitParekh `retain` is no longer used as of ARC. You should replace it with `strong`.

Answer (score 12):

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* name;
```

is better, as `NSString` is immutable and it's child class `NSMutableString` is mutable.

As long as you are using `NSString` through out, you won't see any difference. But when you start using `NSMutableString`, things can get little dicey.

```
NSMutableString *department = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Maths"];

Person *p1 = [Person new];
p1.department = department;

//Here If I play with department then it's not going to affect p1 as the property was copy
//e.g.
[department appendString:@"You're in English dept."];
```

Had it been just retain it would have changed the department of the `p1`.
So having copy is prefered in this case.

Answer (score 5):

If `NSString` is `mutable` then it gets `copied`. If its not, then it is `retained`
If you will use `copy`, a new copy for the string will be created hence different memory address too. Whereas, if you will use `retain` then it will be in the same memory address only the retain counter will change.

Comment: You mean that when in property if NSString property then i use retain and when i am using NSMutableString then i need to use COPY right ?

Comment: NSString is never mutable. Hence the need for NSMutableString...