# Weak Property Of ViewController is not set some time

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I'm using MMDrawerController And want passing data from one view controller to Another view controller as(HomeViewController to DetailViewController)

*HomeViewController view controller*

```
Category *categoryItem = [category objectAtIndex:cellIndex];
         UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        DetailsViewController * centerVC=(DetailsViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController"];
                    centerVC.catName= categoryItem.name ;
            centerVC.catUrl=categoryItem.url;
            UINavigationController * centerNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:centerVC];
            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            appDelegate.drawerController.centerViewController=centerNav;
```

And In ViewDidLoad We Want access property as
*DetailsViewController view controller*
**DetailsViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSString* catName;
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSString* catUrl;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

self.navigationItem.title = [_catName uppercaseString];

}
```

But some time _catName has value nil.

Is there anything wrong ,If Then plz suggest.

If problem with defining properties weak then what type property I choose for view controller property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`weak` says "keep this as long as someone else points to it strongly".
So your property catName and catUrl will sustain only until categoryItem is in memory.

Instead you can use `copy`.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* catName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* catUrl;
```

A copy guarantees that the string you have will not change. Let's say you want to avoid something passing a mutable string and then changing it without you knowing.

For example,

```
NSMutableString *someRandomString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"stackoverflow"];

Entrepreneur * entrepreneur = [[Entrepreneur alloc] init];
entrepreneur.name = someRandomString;

[someRandomString setString:@"Steve Jobs"];
```

Now, the value of *name* property of *Entrepreneur* class will be dependent on whether the property is declared as `strong` or `copy`; it will be @"Steve Jobs" if the property is declared as `strong`, and @"stackoverflow" in case the property is declared as `copy`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing data from appdelegate make your property as a strong reference. and this will also help you.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* catUrl;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* catName;
```

[Differences between strong and weak in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013587/differences-between-strong-and-weak-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Of course the problem is with weak NSString property. You should have strong reference on NSString *catName and NSString* catUrl, because they have to be in memory.
In you case you catName and catUrl are disappeared after method (where they had been set up) is completed.

But you should set a copy property parameter because of NSString (more about this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31217735/5151981)

So your code should look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *catName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *catURLString;
```

Answer (score 0):

please use nonatomic and retain

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* catUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* catName;
```